# Failed to execute hrmp open request on polkadot

Tags: parachain, xcm, hrmp

We recently sent XCM messages from Phala to Polkadot to send HRMP open requests to PolkaDex parachain. We constructed the message as usual, but the message failed to execute on Polkadot. I haven't figured the issue out after rechecking the message we send.
You can find the record [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/xcm_message/polkadot-63f33ddf532c5fbc288811861c20ab0aa596c9e3), and I do find something strange that the proofSize is somehow 0, which normally will cause failure, but don't know why it happened since I didn't give 0 on our message.
[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful to see some xcm logs(trace & debug) after reproducing this locally. Either xcm-simulator or xcm-emulator should be good tools for that.